# Apply css to first table

Tags: html, css

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/w361a9hg/

**When you see fiddle first strach result window.** otherwise you want see what i want.

> My problem is that I crate table and apply css all working fine but
>   now i want to apply **border-left: 1px dotted;** to only **first table.**

```
<div class='openDiv hide'>
    <table id="addPropertyValue1"></table>
    <table id="addPropertyValue2"></table>
    <table id="addPropertyValue3"></table>
    <table id="addPropertyValue4"></table>
    <table id="addPropertyValue5"></table>
</div>
```

I tried with first-child .but not working

```
.openDiv :first-child{
        border-left: 1px dotted;
    }
```

> **Note** : dont apply css on id directly like

```
.openDiv #addPropertyValue1{
    border-left: 1px dotted;
}
```

want pure css solution will help me I don't want jquery or javascript to apply dynamic class on table

Comment: `.openDiv table:first-child`

Comment: When you don't want to use jquery, please remove the jquery tag from the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `first-child` for table inside `.openDiv`.

Like this:

```
.openDiv table:first-child {
    border-left:1px dotted;
}
```

[Updated fiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/w361a9hg/2/)

Comment: i have one question can you tell me  difference between first-of-type   and  .openDiv table:first-child which is best practices

Comment: `first-of-type`  represents the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element, `first-child` represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

Comment: @AlexChar i think in answer first-of-type is perfect below one more answer has first-chiled type of solution so if other user comes then they understand the two ways of solutions and  there difference if both answer is same then it has nothing use full

Comment: For a better understanding check this for [:first-child](http://jsfiddle.net/b776m3pk/1/) and [:first-of-type](http://jsfiddle.net/b776m3pk/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the css on first child

```
.openDiv table:first-child{
    border-left: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.openDiv table:nth-child(1){
    border-left: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

In order to continue an go on with the rest of the tables

```
.openDiv table:nth-child(2){
    border-left: 1px dotted #000;
}
.openDiv table:nth-child(3){
    border-left: 1px dotted #000;
}
.openDiv table:nth-child(4){
    border-left: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

etc..